# PHP and Basic Auth

Tags: javascript, php, basic-authentication

I know there are many Q&A for this topic, so far nothing worked for me.

I make a cross site HTTP request with Javascript/XMLHttpRequest from my PC to my server (Ubuntu/Apache/PHP 7.4):

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', src, true, username, password);
client.withCredentials = true;
```

The headers sent by my PHP script:

```
function print_headers($content_type) {
       $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '*';
       
       if (substr($referer, strlen($referer) - 1) == '/') {
           $referer = substr($referer, 0, strlen($referer) - 1); 
       }
       
       header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $referer);
       header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
       header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
       header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,content-type");
       header($content_type);
}
```

It works without Basic Auth, for Basic Auth I cannot get username/password from PHP_AUTH_USER and PHP_AUTH_PW (they are empty):

$username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];

$password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

It is often recommended to use this RewriteRule in Apache config or htaccess:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

and in PHP:

```
list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':' , base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));
```

It doesn't work. The Apache config for my site:

```
<Directory "/var/www/my.site.com/">
    RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(?!admin).*$ index.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add header to your xhr request? like:

```
client.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
```

Comment: I added that line and Chrome says: "has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status"

Comment: then something is wrong with cors configuration on the server side, try to change the header to `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`